# Replace one column of a dataframe's values with another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a table like this: unique IDs might have 1 entry or they might have many entries.

| ID | Start | Stop | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1/1/2021 | 1/31/2021 | 270 |
| 101 | 2/1/2020 | 3/31/2020 | 270 |
| 102 | 1/1/2021 | 3/29/2020 | 208 |
| 102 | 3/30/2020 | 3/31/2020 | 208 |
| 103 | 1/1/2020 | 3/31/2020 | 210 |
| 104 | 1/1/2020 | 1/2/2020 | 130 |
| 104 | 1/3/2020 | 3/31/2020 | 130 |
| 105 | 1/1/2020 | 3/31/2020 | 160 |

I need to replace the number in the days column based off another dataframe, which gives a new Days number for each ID. This dataframe looks like:

| ID | Days |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 290 |
| 102 | 250 |
| 103 | 215 |
| 104 | 180 |
| 105 | 175 |

How can I replace the Days column in the first dataframe with the Days information for each ID in the second dataframe? My end result should look thus:

| ID | Start | Stop | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1/1/2021 | 1/31/2021 | 290 |
| 101 | 2/1/2020 | 3/31/2020 | 290 |
| 102 | 1/1/2021 | 3/29/2020 | 250 |
| 102 | 3/30/2020 | 3/31/2020 | 250 |
| 103 | 1/1/2020 | 3/31/2020 | 215 |
| 104 | 1/1/2020 | 1/2/2020 | 180 |
| 104 | 1/3/2020 | 3/31/2020 | 180 |
| 105 | 1/1/2020 | 3/31/2020 | 175 |

I tried df.update and converting the second dataframe to a dictionary and using .map but with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: The `ID`-`Days` mapping dataframe has two entries for `ID 102`. Is that a typo?

Comment: where is your code? What means "no success" ? Did you get error message? Show this message in question.

Comment: Yes sorry that was a typo. I've fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
df_1.drop(columns=Days, inplace=True)
final = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID')
final.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_1["Days"] = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on="ID")["Days_y"]
print(df_1)
```

Prints:

```
    ID      Start       Stop  Days
0  101   1/1/2021  1/31/2021   290
1  101   2/1/2020  3/31/2020   290
2  102   1/1/2021  3/29/2020   250
3  102  3/30/2020  3/31/2020   250
4  103   1/1/2020  3/31/2020   215
5  104   1/1/2020   1/2/2020   180
6  104   1/3/2020  3/31/2020   180
7  105   1/1/2020  3/31/2020   175
```